# Get Windows login password - Python

Tags: windows, windows-7, python-3.x, credentials

How would I get the user password for the current account on Windows 7 in python?

My vision of how it might work:

```
...
passwd = someWindowsApi.GetUserPassword()
print("Your current password is: " + passwd)
...
```

Then running the script would output something like this:

```
>python whatsmypassword.py
```

> Your password is "password" Seriously? You might as well not have a
>   password. This incident will be reported to the security fanatics
>   foundation!

I am assuming that this script would have to be run as administrator, and that is fine.

Comment: Do you really think there is a Windows API just laying around that gives the users password to any program that asks for it? The easiest way to acquire the password is to ask the user for it:  `input("Login Password: ")`. And if, for some reason, you absolutely need to get the password without the users permission, it won't be as easy as your describing it.

Comment: That's fine. If it's challenging, so be it. I just want to know how.

Comment: Bear in mind, that this is something you generally shouldn't do, most users don't want their passwords stolen. I advise that you just ask for it.

Comment: I see it is 6 years old question,but omg i am looking for the answer now!.as i see we will have to crack,decode windows System files :(

Comment: Cmon! There gotta be a solution.

Comment: I also looking for solution of this problem after 8 years